# how to add a matrix to an ArrayList in java

Tags: java, arrays

I need to add a number of matrces to an arraylist or some sort of collection in order to recall them at a later stage

I have tried the arraylist and arraycopy

```
List<Double> al = new ArrayList<>();
double [][] k = new double [d.length][d[0].length];

System.arraycopy (d,0,k,0,d.length);

for (int i1 =0; i1 < d.length; i1++)
    k[i1] = k.add(D[i1]);
al.add(k[i1]);
for (Integer x : k)
    System.out.print(x + " ");
print2D(k);
```

I need an array of say 4x4 matrices
If I do say `al.add(d);` I get error: cannot find suitable method to add double
even when `al.add(Matrix)`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the array as type for your generics. What you want is `List<double[][]>` and not `List<Double>`. Then you will be able to add your matrices to the list.

The addition is simple, just

```
list.add(matrix);
// or in your case:
al.add(k);
```

no need to copy anything around or access the individual entries in the matrices.

You can retrieve matrices via `get` for example:

```
double[][] firstMatrix = list.get(0);
```

Comment: Thanks Butiri & Zabuza I have corrected  the List<Double  [][]> but still get this error: no suitable method found for add(double[][])
     al.add(k); and also this error: incompatible types: Double[][] cannot be converted to double[][], please explain
   double[][] firstMatrix = al.get(0);

Comment: As I said, it is `double[][]` and not `Double[][]`.

Answer (score 0):

The list must be a list of matrices, and you are declaring a list of Doubles. Try something like this:

```
List<double[][]> list = new ArrayList<>();
    double[][] matrix = {{1D,1D},{2D,2D}};
    list.add(matrix);
```

Hope that helps!